# Tableau - creating small multiples chart showing frequency of various keywords in a covid-19 vaccine side effect text field

Tags: graph, charts, data-visualization, tableau-api

I have a dataset containing about 40,000 rows of text about covid-19 vaccine side effects reported by individuals (it's a free field text provided by vaccine recipients). E.g. "My arm was sore for a few days. Just a bit of pain." or "I had a slight headache and a bit of nausea." Other columns state their age, gender, and a few other factors.

My end goal is to show the frequency of various side effect keywords (e.g. "tired" or "headache") by vaccine manufacturer and to allow users to filter it by age and gender. For example, "female 40-49" and then a set of graphs (small multiples?) showing each side effect.

Here's where I've gotten:[image]

I used the contains function to create a sheet of each side effect. Then I did calculate % of column so that it shows %s, not raw #s. I then combined all the sheets into a dashboard.

**1) How do I hide the "no" column? I only want to show the % yes.** E.g. If it's 3% yes and 97% no, I just want to show 3% said yes.
**2) How do I filter on the dashboard level, not the sheet level?** E.g. If someone wants to see the side effects for men aged 30-39 or perhaps females 60-69. I don't want them to have to filter for every single side effect one by one.

Answer (score 1):

To hide the No, try right-clicking on the No and hiding it. I can't be sure that will work, it might leave all of your % total calcs showing 100%. If that happens, plan B is to use a Tableau late filter, a table calculation.

Create a calculated field:

LOOKUP(ATTR([YesNoField]),0)

Filter on that field to remove the "NO". You'll need to do that on every worksheet (it looks like you're using multiple worksheets).

To filter at a dashboard level, which doesn't work for table calculation filters, but does work for normal filters, show the filter field on your dashboard, then in the filter settings you can tell it to affect all sheets on the dashboard. Right click on the filter in the dashboard for this option.